# Editing a .sav file and re-naming it back. (simple)

Tags: file, rename, spss, file-rename

I have a `xxx.sav` file I would like to edit. If i rename the file like `xxx.txt.gz` I can unzip it and get to the content which I would like to edit. I have done all of that.
However I cannot manage to get it back into .SAV format. Is there a way which I can do this after changing a line of code in the .txt?

Comment: Changing a filename should be pretty simple? Unixbased could just be `mv xxx.txt.gz xxx.sav`, right? Or are there compatibility issues?

Comment: @FrederikSpang I can break it down to .txt and edit it. However when I name the file back to 'xxx.txt.gz', then to 'xxx.sav'. Its fine. However, when you edit the sav file again to 'xxx.txt.gz' its fails.

Comment: Remember you need to actually gzip the file, not just rename it to .gz - and unzip correctly before editing! That might cause some problems?
Edit: rename to txt.gz - unzip to .txt - edit - gzip to .txt.gz - rename to .sav ?

Comment: @FrederikSpang, if I have to actually gzip the file, will I also have to "actually" .sav the file aswell? Also, how can I go along of "gzip"ing a file?

Comment: @FrederikSpang your method works. Please place it in an answer so I can give you points. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember gzipping your file back and forth, to avoid issues. Your workflow should look something like this:

```
rename to txt.gz -> 
unzip to .txt -> 
edit -> 
gzip to .txt.gz
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about SPSS sav files?  Those are binary and cannot be edited.